# Selection of Second Look up on basis of First Loook up data

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have one Custom object "Client and other one is Facility", there is look up relation in this When I Save any Facility record Client is Mandatory. Now I am giving both these object records into third object name Myobject as lookup again, but I want  the  data of client on the basis of facility means

Client A - Faciltiy A

Client B - Faciltiy A

Client C - Faciltiy A

Client D- Faciltiy A

Client E - Faciltiy B

Client F - Faciltiy B

If  i select Facility A than only Clinet A,B,C,D should be shown in look up

Regards

Raman

Answer (score -1):

I believe you'll need a custom lookup page to facilitate this.

Good guide here:

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2011/08/12/roll-your-own-salesforce-lookup-popup-window/

Comment: Or, you can use standard functionality.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the standard feature "Filtered Lookups" to enforce this logic. Go to MyObject, select the Client lookup field, add a mandatory filter lookup that states that Client Facility must equal MyObject Facility.